# How to zoom camera using webRTC in android

Tags: android, libjingle, webrtc-android

Is there any API to **zoom camera** using webRTC in android. I read this [link](https://gist.github.com/KushtrimPacaj/ac5b59b5322dc5a1db0d75f31d6a2b30) but I didn't find setZoom or isZoomSupported methods in webRTC library. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try writing CustomCameraCapturer ?  you want to zoom camera frame on view surface or want to send zoomed frame to network stream ?

Comment: I want to zoom camera frame on view surface like https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/update-camera-zoom.html

Comment: Have you found the solution? @ShashankGupta

Comment: @JaswantSingh Didn't find any solution till now. If you get any resolution, please share with me.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, have you found a solution?

Comment: @afsar-edrisy, any pointer on your suggestion? It seems promising

Comment: @Cesar Mauri Sorry to say, I didn't find any solution yet. If you get kindly share with me also.